# Did Obama say the USA is "no longer a Christian Nation"?

Tags: united-states, politics, quotes, barack-obama

In 2007, did Barrack Obama declare that the USA "was no longer a Christian Nation"?  This was in an email asking Christians to band together against Obama.

Comment: The US was NEVER a christian nation... The US is a nation OF christians.  Huge distinction.  I suggest anyone who thinks otehrwise read the Constitution (Article VI and 1st amendment), Article 11 of the 1797 Treaty of Tripoli, the writings of the founders, etc. http://www.earlyamerica.com/review/summer97/secular.html  and http://larianlequella.blogspot.co.il/2008/12/not-christian-nation-just-nation-of.shtml

Comment: And in fact, many of the founding fathers were unitarians, theists, or otherwise not capital-C "Christian". So, yes, we were never intended to be Christian nation if by that you mean a nation that considers Christianity inherently superior to any other (or no) religion.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella: I don't think the question is asking whether the US is a Christian nation or not, merely whether Obama said that it was not.  Certainly enough people believe (rightly or wrongly) that it is, or should be, to make the statement controversial and worthy of note.  I fear your comment may be an invitation to an off-topic historical/political discussion of indeterminate length.

Comment: @NateEldredge understood, just the indignant fervor over the deliberately innacurate quote plays to a narrative that the majority of the US population actually believes we are indeed a christian nation...  I just wanted to make that clear from the start.  As for a long debate, a fact is a fact, only the factually challeneged will make an issue of it.

Comment: The US has never been a theocracy, and the Constitution expressly protects against it.  Still, the Constitution and our form of government is expressly for a moral and religious people according to John Adams.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella There's more on that subject at [5 Reasons America Is Not -- And Has Never Been -- a Christian Nation](http://www.alternet.org/story/155985/5_reasons_america_is_not_--_and_has_never_been_--_a_christian_nation)

Comment: Of course, printing "In God we trust" on every single banknote in God's own country doesn't look very secular on first sight ...

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Agreed, but, of course, it shouldn't be on our money. It fortunately wasn't exactly a public decision; but it'd now be an unfortunate controversy to remove it in the same way it was put on.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, but "We're better than those godless commies" doesn't sound as good.

Comment: @LarianLeQuella Please don't write "We" when talking about the USA. It's is an international forum :)

Comment: Aussie speaking: So what does that whole 'one nation under God' bit mean in your pledge of allegiance?

Answer (score 83):

[Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tmC3IevZiik)

> Whatever we once were, we are no longer a Christian nation – at least, not just. We are also a Jewish nation, a Muslim nation, a Buddhist nation, and a Hindu nation, and a nation of nonbelievers.

See also [Obama and the “Christian Nation” Quote](http://www.factcheck.org/2008/08/obama-and-the-christian-nation-quote/), which says it was spoken on June 28, 2006, and says that according to his prepared remarks he was meant to say (which would have been smoother),

> Given the increasing diversity of America's population, the dangers of sectarianism have never been greater. Whatever we once were, **we are no longer just a Christian nation**; we are also a Jewish nation, a Muslim nation, a Buddhist nation, a Hindu nation, and a nation of nonbelievers.

---

The following is a link to the complete text of the speech:

[TOPIC: Our Past, Our Future & Vision for America

June 28, 2006

“Call to Renewal' Keynote Address”](http://obamaspeeches.com/081-Call-to-Renewal-Keynote-Address-Obama-Speech.htm)

It opens with his reaction to someone who claimed that, "Jesus Christ would not vote for Barack Obama. Christ would not vote for Barack Obama because Barack Obama has behaved in a way that it is inconceivable for Christ to have behaved."

At the end he shares two prayers:

- "a prayer that I might extend the same presumption of good faith to others that the doctor had extended to me"
- "a hope that we can live with one another in a way that reconciles the beliefs of each with the good of all".

Comment: Does this count as *declare* or is it just *observe* or something similar?

Comment: And look how nicely the original "quote" was taken out of context. If anything, this quote seems to imply that the current state (with christianity losing its dominance) is *worse* (or more challenging). You could just as easily use the quote as a rallying cry for the christian fundamentalists :D

Comment: @Luaan Re. quoting out of context, I updated the answer to include a link to the entire speech.

Comment: Essentially, Obama said "we're not just a Christian nation." He flubbed a bit, and then had to go back to fix it.